# Require.js minification

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

How does minification and caching happen when we use require.js
For example: I have 4 scripts - student.js, studentFactory.js, studentEnrollment.js, studentResults.js

studentFactory.js, studentEnrollment.js and studentResults.js is dependent on student.js

Now, I know that require does a minification on all its dependencies. 
Lets assume the following structure :

studentFactory.js :
define(["student.js"], function(student){...})

studentEnrollment.js :
define(["student.js", "studentFactory"], function(student, studentFactory){...})

studentResults.js :
define(["student.js", "studentEnrollment"], function(student, studentEnrollment){...})

How does the caching and minification work on this. I have dependencies for student.js in all these and when the first file among these 3 is called, I will have student.js. Ideally I do not have to download it again. Even if the caching works, this has to make 3 network calls at the minimum to get studentFactory.js, studentEnrollment.js, studentResults.js.

I am using asp.net mvc. Wouldn't it be better to creat a bundle in asp.net mvc which would have all these 4 files. This bundle will be referenced in my student.html. So, this will be done in one network call.

Answer (score 0):

You can build all modules and there dependencies in one file with [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics)